# Magento under PHP 5.4 Webserver - fatal: getFrontNameByRoute() on non-object

Tags: magento-1.7, ee-1.12, devops, php-5.4

Has anyone managed to get Magento running under PHP 5.4 with the **built-in web server**?  I have used the [HTRouter PHAR](https://github.com/jaytaph/HTRouter) to mimic .htaccess rules - but so far I'm coming up empty, all roads at the moment lead to

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontNameByRoute() on a non-object`

Comment: Magento 1.7.x runs fine on PHP 5.4.14 on Apache as php_mod or PHP_FPM, tried them both in VM running Ubuntu. As for built in Server, that one I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I had a quick look into this and got it running pretty easily.

#### Instructions for Debian

```
cat >> /etc/apt/sources.lst <<EOF
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
EOF

wget -qO - http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg | apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-cli php5-mysqlnd php5-mcrypt php5-common php-pear php5-dev php5-mysql php5-curl php5-mcrypt php5-gd php5-cli php5-xsl php5-imagick
```

Then I made a simple router (instead of using HTRouter), that mimicked the rules in a stock Magento `.htaccess`

```
<?php

  if (preg_match('#^/api/rest#', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
      $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = 'api.php?type=rest';
  } elseif (preg_match('#^/(media|skin|js)#', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
      return false;
  } elseif (file_exists(".".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]))  {
      return false;
  } else {
      include_once 'index.php';
  }

?>
```

Then started the PHP server and pointed it at `router.php` (the file from above).

```
php -S 172.16.0.249:80 router.php
```

Works just fine :)

<sup>Content sourced from [sonassi.com](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/running-magento-in-php-5-4s-built-in-web-server/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Per the [System Requirements](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements), Magento requires "PHP 5.2.13 - 5.3.15".

Magento 2 (last I heard) does not even yet fully support PHP 5.4 yet…although there is a lot of debate on whether or not to require it, and final support for it is obvious.

Some of these compatibility issues stem from, I believe, issues in PHP 5.4's SimpleXML implementation: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62639

My conclusion: Stick with the latest PHP 5.3.x build and don't risk using non-officially supported

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply - I understand what is and isn't supported; I'm trying to see if anyone else is experimenting with it at the moment. Too much time with Laravel makes me want this feature I suppose...

Comment: ok, so more of a what's been messed with to see if we can get it to work… gotcha.

Comment: It's more for experimentation than anything else - I have about 15 CentOS VMs and a bunch of boilerplate VMs  set up with Magento at all different levels of CE/EE - I'm just curious how this would work to bootstrap new features/development.  If you've ever seen it in action, Laravel has a pretty impressive demo where they `git clone` and `php -S 0.0.0.0:80` and BOOM - demo app. Of course, Magento is a platform on top of Zend and I'm sure I could replicate that kind of demo with ZF.